# Post_Logout_Redirect_Uri does not redirect when authenticating using azure

Tags: azure, owin, azure-active-directory

Using OWIN & OpenId to authenticate users for my basic web application using Azure Active Directory, as described in the Readme.md in Microsoft's sample project here:https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect

The following item is in my web.config:

`<add key="ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri" value="https://localhost:44320/" />`

The Startup.Auth is as follows:

```
    private static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
    private static string aadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"];
    private static string tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"];
    private static string postLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri"];

    string authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, aadInstance, tenant);

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = authority,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44320/Home/About",
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    AuthenticationFailed = context => 
                    {
                        context.HandleResponse();
                        context.Response.Redirect("/Error?message=" + context.Exception.Message);
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                }
            });
    }
}
```

However the microsoft.com website does not redirect even though the redirect URI made it into it's URL[image]

Comment: I had this issue ages ago, what solved it for me was to clear my entire browsing history. Give that a try and let me know if it works.

Comment: No that does not work

Comment: Have you deployed the application yet to see if it redirects without using localhost?

Comment: No, but I mean I can just add a URI like ```http://www.google.com``` and it still doesnt redirect.Even if I add that to the ReplyURLs in Azure

Comment: do you have a sign up or sign in policy ? 

Try adding "?p=your_policy" as query param and then follow it with the post logout redirect url like so 
[https://login.microsoftonline.com/YOUR_TENANT/oauth2/logout?p=your_policy&post_logout_redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2F](https://login.microsoftonline.com/MY_TENANT/oauth2/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmicway.com.au%2F)

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find a solution?

Comment: @vcattin I have added the answer after doing a lot of investigation

Comment: @Vicky where can I find policy ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I spent a lot of time properly figuring out how to get this to work. Even though 3 years ago we just didn't bother. There seemed to be a lot of people on the internet with this issue and I wanted to make sure this is answered for everyone.

The solution below applies for the issue occurring for a standard Azure AD. It also applies to Azure AD B2C, in the circumstance where you sign in with an organizational account. (Note that this solution does not cover the new b2clogin URIs and user flow technique, as it didn't exist at the time that I asked the question)

1. At the time this was asked, there appeared to be a bug of some kind in Azure. A workaround was as follows: The URI you are using as a post logout redirect must be specified in both the reply URLs and as the Front Channel Logout URL. Normally front-channel logout is a silent request that the IDP sends to your application to allow you to run logic to clear cookies, but doesn't cause a redirect. Before implementing this you should check if Microsoft has fixed the issue.
   [image]
   Be careful of accidentally adding trailing slashes at the end of your URIs. Try to keep them **perfectly** identical here and in your client application.
2. An authority of the form `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<org-name>.onmicrosoft.com/V2.0` would not work. For a standard Azure AD I had to change the authority to be of the form  `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>/V2.0` for a specific tenant or `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/V2.0` which is also used in some scenarios I think.
   For B2C AD tenants it only works for the `common` endpoint above.

Side note 1: with the `common` endpoint you have to set `ValidateIssuer` to false in the token validation parameters or you will get an exception. Doing the validation correctly is outside the scope of this SO question.

Side note 2: When searching for this issue on Google you might come across some solutions to the problem for people authenticating against Identity Server. The solutions and the specification suggest you to add an id_token_hint to your signout request. This was neither sufficient nor necessary for me to get the redirect working for Azure AD.

Comment: I did everything except adding the URI on the "Front-channel logout URL" as my redirect URI is `http://` and this apparently accepts only `https://`

Comment: "The URI you are using as a post logout redirect must be specified in both the reply URLs and as the Front Channel Logout URL. " This is just wrong. You can have multiple post logout redirects, it has nothing to do with FrontChannelLogout.

Comment: @pkExec While I agree with you, at the time this was the only way I could get it to work. It was a workaround for a possible bug in Azure. I will edit my answer to reflect that

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't work anyway be aware of this Azure AD post logout redirection behavior, that caused troubles in my case:

- It didn't work for root accounts of the tenant, that is my personal
  account, which created Azure subscription.
- But it worked for new accounts I created inside of my subscription.